# Filtering using another cells value as the filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I have two lists:

- one "master" list containing ALL usernames and employee numbers
- another list of say 100 random employee numbers.

I would like to filter that list based on the "random employee numbers". What would be the simplest way to perform this?

Comment: excel and mac. 2011? 2016?

Answer (score 1):

Add a third column to your master list titled **RandomFilter**

Enter this formula and copy down for each row you have with data:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2,RandomEmployeeNumbers!$A$1:$A$100,0),"Show"),"Hide")
```

The `MATCH()` function checks whether each employee number in your master list appears in your list of random numbers. `IF()` and `IFERROR()` tells Excel what to do if there is a match.

You will need to adjust the formula so that instead of **B2** you enter the cell reference for the top employee number in your master list, and instead of **RandomEmployeeNumbers!$A$1:$A$100** you enter the range of cells where your 100 random numbers are. Remember to use $ so the formula doesn't break when you copy down.

Then simply filter to only display rows saying **Show**.

Comment: Good answer, it could be read that the "master" has names and numbers in the same cell.

Comment: Good point - I read the question as saying there were two columns in the master list. If I'm wrong the OP is welcome to correct me :)

Comment: Yeah, that's how I read it too